# Create numpy array from panda daataframe inside a For loop

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Lets say that i have the following dataframe:

```
data = {"Names": ["Ray", "John", "Mole", "Smith", "Jay", "Marc", "Tom", "Rick"],
        "Sports": ["Soccer", "Judo", "Tenis", "Judo", "Tenis","Soccer","Judo","Tenis"]}
```

I want to have a for loop like that for each unique Sport i am able to retrieve a numpy array containing the Names of people playing that sport. In pseudo code that can be explainded as

```
for unique sport in sports:
    nArray= numpy array of names of people practicing sport
    ---------
    Do something with nArray
    -------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with `np.array`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
s = df.groupby('Sports')['Names'].apply(np.array)
print (s)
Sports
Judo      [John, Smith, Tom]
Soccer           [Ray, Marc]
Tenis      [Mole, Jay, Rick]
Name: Names, dtype: object

for sport, name in s.items():
    print (name)

    ['John' 'Smith' 'Tom']
    ['Ray' 'Marc']
    ['Mole' 'Jay' 'Rick']
```

Comment: Sports are already unique, Names are sufficient as list `['Names'].apply(list)`

Comment: sports are uniqed by groupby. The OP said " for each unique Sport i am able to retrieve a numpy array containing the Names of people"

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest - Why do you think my answer not do it?

Comment: I just have a limitation.  This is returning me unique Names,. I need something that returns all  Names even if they are duplicated , on the order it founds them on the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

one way to go

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
for sport in df.Sports.unique():
    list_of_names = list(df[df.Sports == sport].Names)
    data = np.array(list_of_names)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by pandas library for get list array of sport persons name.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = {"Names": ["Ray", "John", "Mole", "Smith", "Jay", "Marc", "Tom", "Rick"],
        "Sports": ["Soccer", "Judo", "Tenis", "Judo", "Tenis","Soccer","Judo","Tenis"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

unique_sports = df['Sports'].unique()

for sport in unique_sports:
    uniqueNames = np.array(df[df['Sports'] == sport]['Names'])

print(uniqueNames)
```

**Result :**

```
['Mole' 'Jay' 'Rick']
```